# Why would I break my Java web application into two repositories on git?

Tags: java, git

Okay, I just need clarification, I don't want to be mean and I'm not use to this idea.

I have been requested to work with a team and build a java web application that links into multiple API's. Why would I not use some sort of framework (Spring,MVC,JSP,etc.)? Instead I was asked to design the web pages and place them into one Git repository, then design the back-end of the application and add it to another repository. We will then integrate the two (I'm not sure how, which might be were they are losing me) Is this normal/should we be doing this?

Comment: Two separate issues: a) breaking up an application into multiple modules/projects to enforce proper layering and facilitate code reuse is common  b) if you want to distribute/publish/control access to modules/projects separately using git you need to make multiple repositories (because the repository is the granularity of sharing in git)

Comment: "Why would I not use some sort of framework?" Maybe you should, maybe you are. But even if you use Spring/MVC/JSP, those are general purpose libraries and you will always have to write application code, some of it will be back-end, some of it will be front-end, so that does not avoid the "issue" you mention.

Comment: Okay, this is the first time I've ever done something like this. @Thilo can you go infor a little more detail about reuse of code? Are you saying if we want to reuse the views in another project? From my understanding it's all suppose to deploy to a server and the pages need to be dynamic (hence link in with the java backend).

Comment: I don't know your project, but usually it's the backend code that gets reused (for example for different front-ends, or API client connector libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes perfect sense to separate the backend from the frontend since they could be deployed separately, even on different machines, and also they will produce 2 different artifacts (a jar file and a bunch of html pages). If you are using Maven  you could consider to have a parent project and split the backend and the frontend in 2 different modules. Regarding git you could explore the submodules feature or just create 2 different folders within the same repository. I prefer the former. Regarding the integration, usually the backend simply expose REST Endpoint and the frontend perform AJAX calls to interact.

Comment: Okay, this makes a lot more sense. Thank you, this is my first time working with a codebase that takes a large amount of hits/sec. I've always been building applications with a framework that does the middleware communication from front-end to back-end.

Comment: @John I'm pretty sure you can vote on answers that are posted on your own question

Answer (score 0):

If they later decide to keep your front end, but replace the back end with another implementation, or vice versa .. Or if they want to get rid of both, but not simultaneously, they can toss you, and hire to different guys to do front end and back end separately.

Answer (score 0):

This approach gives you loose coupling and separation of concerns. You entirely separate application-behavior from user-interface/presentation. The loose coupling gives you a few advantages:

- Makes it easy to build different types of clients for your application; not just a web-based one. For example, it would be much easier to build a mobile-client since the interface to your application is only through its public API.
- Makes it easy to use different front-end frameworks or switch to another framework entirely.
- Prevents abstraction-leakage from the back-end into the presentation layer.
- Doesn't tie the release-cycle of the front-end to the back-end.

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to see the picture a lot better now. This makes a lot more sense, thank you guys!